# Quickly exchanging data between two computers

Tags: java, php

I have been experimenting with ways to use the processing power of two computers together as one (not by physically connecting them, but by splitting the task in half and each computer does a half, then the result from the "helper" computer is sent back to be combined with the result from the "main" computer via internet)

I've been using this method to compute fractal images and it works great. The left half and the right half of the image are computed on separate computers, then combined into one. The process of sending one half of the image to the other computer and combining them takes maybe a second, so the efficiency is great and cuts time down by about half.

The problem comes when you want to do this "multi computer processing" with something that needs data exchanged very frequently.
For example, I'd like to use this for something like an n-body simulation. You need the data exchange to happen multiple times per second, so if the exchange takes about a second it actually takes much longer to try and use two computers then it would with one.

So how do online video games do it? The players around you, what they are doing, what they are wearing, everything going on has to be exchanged between everyone playing many times per second.

I'm just looking for general ideas on how to send larger amounts of data and at fast speeds. 
The way I have been doing it is with PHP on a free hosting site. The helper computer will compute its half of the data then sends it to the PHP file which saves that data somewhere. Then the main computer reads this and combines it with the data it computed already.
I have a feeling PHP isn't the way to go, but I don't know much about this sort of thing.

Comment: What is your communication mechanism that you are currently using with PHP? As in, Sockets, HTTP requests... ?

Comment: As for online games, a) Many times might in most general cases amount to 1-2 times b) They use a server client model in most cases so server broadcasts about all, it is not peer to peer comm

Comment: I believe it would be HTTP requests? I have c# code that sends the data as a post variable to the php file.
not exactly sure what that means though.

Answer (score 2):

Your first step will be to move from using HTTP Requests to using Sockets directly - this will give you much more control over the communication, and give you improved performance by reducing the overhead of the HTTP protocol (this is potentially pretty significant). Plus, with sockets you can more easily have your programs communicate to each other directly, rather than through the PHP-based software.

There are a ton of guides online as to how you would do this sort of system, and I would recommend Googling things like "game networking" and "distributed computing".

Here is one series of articles that I have found useful in the past, that covers the sort of things that you will want to read about: http://gafferongames.com/networking-for-game-programmers/

(He doesn't use Java, but the ideas are universal)

Comment: Thanks for this information the link looks very helpful. I was thinking there might be a good way to do it using java

Comment: Happy to help - networking is the fun that keeps on giving, and giving...